# Remove a variety of lines in a text file

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep, cat

I've been trying to implement a bash script that reads from wordnet's online database and have been wondering if there is a way to remove a variety text files with one command.

Example FileDump:

```
**** Noun ****
(n)hello, hullo, hi, howdy, how-do-you-do (an expression of greeting) "every morning they exchanged polite hellos"
**** Verb ****
(v)run (move fast by using one's feet, with one foot off the ground at any given time) "Don't run--you'll be out of breath"; "The children ran to the store"
**** Adjective ****
(adj)running ((of fluids) moving or issuing in a stream) "as mountain stream with freely running water"; "hovels without running water"
```

I just need to remove the lines which describe aspects of grammar e.g.

```
**** Noun ****
**** Verb ****
**** Adjective ****
```

So that I have a clean file with only definitions of the words:

```
(n)hello, hullo, hi, howdy, how-do-you-do (an expression of greeting) "every morning they exchanged polite hellos"
(v)run (move fast by using one's feet, with one foot off the ground at any given time) "Don't run--you'll be out of breath"; "The children ran to the store"
(adj)running ((of fluids) moving or issuing in a stream) "as mountain stream with freely running water"; "hovels without running water"
```

The * symbols around the grammatical terms are tripping me up in sed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to select whole lines from a file based just on the content of those lines, `grep` is probably the most suitable tool available. However, some characters, such as your stars, have special meanings to `grep`, so need to be "escaped" with a backslash. This will print just the lines starting with four stars and a space:

```
grep "^\*\*\*\* " textfile
```

However, you want to keep the lines which *don't* match that, so you need the `-v` option for `grep` which does just that: prints the lines which *don't* match the pattern.

```
grep -v "\*\*\*\* " textfile
```

That should give you what you want.

Comment: Your explanation, and second piece of code both helped me, and achieved the outcome.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/^\*\{4\} .* \*\{4\}$/d'
```

or a bit looser

```
sed '/^*\{4\}/d'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 sed 's/^*.*//g' test | grep .
```

Comment: Yours achieved the solution as well - but you were just a tad to late for the tick. Both answers achieve the outcome of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
# awk '!/^\*\*+/' file
(n)hello, hullo, hi, howdy, how-do-you-do (an expression of greeting) "every morning they exchanged polite hellos"
(v)run (move fast by using one's feet, with one foot off the ground at any given time) "Don't run--you'll be out of breath"; "The children ran to the store"
(adj)running ((of fluids) moving or issuing in a stream) "as mountain stream with freely running water"; "hovels without running water"
```